# Get the creation time of a file

Tags: files-and-directories, windows

Windows is able to tell me when (date & time) a file in the file system was created or altered. Is it possible to get such information in *Mathematica*, e.g., get the creation time of a text file after importing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See 
[FileDate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileDate.html)

> FileDate["file","type"] gives information on the specified type of
>   date associated with a file.

[Global System Information](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GlobalSystemInformation.html) will unveil more details.

Comment: perfekt, thanks!